# Browser not rendering some websites corrrectly - horizontal width issue

Tags: 18.04, firefox, google-chrome

Just did a fresh install of 18.04.4

Both chrome and firefox are not rendering width correctly when using a smaller browser window. 
Sites seem to have overflow horizontal space. Google, here for example:

[[image: Google renders strangely when using small width window.]

However, interestingly, if I scroll to the right, the footer remains fixed, but the header content moves over (to user image etc)

[image: Other weird symptoms]

Thoughts?